# Is it possible to use dynamic objects with Dynamic LINQ?

Tags: linq, dynamic, properties

Is it possible to use a list of dynamic objects with dynamic LINQ?

If I create a dynamic object with dynamic properties and then want to use Dynamic LINQ on a list of such objects?

For example, I have (where data is a list of dynamic objects):

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = data.Where(x => x.branch_group != "");
```

which works.

And:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = data.Where("branch_group != \"\"");
```

which does NOT work.

---

And if I try to get values using Select I get "No property or field 'xxx' exists in type 'Object'".

This should be possible to do, right?

Has someone done these kinds of things before?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE!**

Yay!

I finally found a solution to this after 24 hours (yes, it´s true) of constant hard investigation and severe hallucinations!

I could actually hear those code lines crunhing in my head and I witnessed universes of civilizations go extinct from trying to solve this problem. I saw space-time itself shiver before the vastness of eternal death which surrounded this domain of unsolvability.

BUT! Then I slept for 4 hours and got the solution in the morning.

The key to solving this problem is to create an object which uses an indexer in such a way that the dynamic LINQ library will use it at runtime using the "it"-keyword.

So, it´s actually possible, although every article, blog, forum, [insert source here] etc I´ve read suggested that it was not.

I may even deserve some credit (or like endless dollar$ or something) for this.
(Yeah, yeah, I´m all over-excited about all this and blah, blah, blah. But it´s damn true!) :P

For code sample, please mail to: johan@codelink.se

Comment: Well, it is actually correct because the use of dynamic LINQ. Sadly though, it only seems to work with compile-time objects and not dynamic run-time objects.

Comment: "For code sample, please mail to: johan@codelink.se" ...or you could just post it here as an answer as intended by this site.

Comment: Well its silly, when you were seeking a solution you were asking for a code demonstration or help in some ways that solves your problem, once you get it by yourself, what on earth you are doing telling for code email me? Does it really make sense to put solution seeker in wait list and email you? What if you dont respond to your emails to somebody as mad as you not sleeping for 24+ hours? even not getting a single minute sleep? Ridiculous!

Comment: Someone should ban this guy ... clearly he adds no value to the community but expects to get help from it ... there would be no sleep lost from me if this guy was not here any more!

Answer (score 1):

using the opensource Impromtu-Interface (found in nuget)

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = data.Where(Impromptu.InvokeGet(x,"branch_group") != "")
```

It's ugly, but it would allow `"branch_group"` to come from a variable, which I assume is the benefit your are looking for over the statement that worked.

Impromptu has [wrappers for all types of dlr calls](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding), since it's open source it's possible to dig into the code and adapt the same techniques into a dynamic linq type syntax, but probably a lot of work.